# Drupal add possibility to change submission id

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7

Hello everybody and thanks for interest

some time ago i have started to use Drupal, but i am not best programmer, i am learning to be, and now i have one little issue.
I am using **Drupal 6 and Webform module**, where i want to **add possibility to webform-results table** - what i need is to add row to results table which after click will **change submission nid** - update mysql webform_submissions table nid to predefined value. (change nid from 21 to 23)

i found webform.result.inc and webform_handler_filed_submission_link.inc files, which displays result table, but i don't knnow how to add this function.

Is it possible and can you somebody help me?
I will be very thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database table has no 'click' event (don't even know where to start correcting that), if you want to change the `nid` in `webform_results` just run this query:

```
// Drupal 6
db_query('UPDATE {webform_results} SET nid = %d WHERE nid = %d', $new_nid, $old_nid);

// Drupal 7
db_update('webform_results')->fields(array('nid' => $new_nid))->condition('nid' => $old_nid)->execute();
```